# Tensorflow Evaluation: Evaluating all Images

Tags: tensorflow

I have built a convolutional neural network with the same iamge format as CIFAR10 and is currently trying to evaluate it, however, I cannot get my code to evaluate all images in the file and I can only read the first image. Even when I call a loop, it only prints the result over and over again. I have tested it on single images too.

My code is shown below:

```
import tensorflow as tf

import main
import Process
import Input

eval_dir = "/Users/Zanhuang/Desktop/NNP/model.ckpt-250"
checkpoint_dir = "/Users/Zanhuang/Desktop/NNP/checkpoint"


def evaluate():
  with tf.Graph().as_default() as g:
    images, labels = Process.eval_inputs()
    forward_propgation_results = Process.forward_propagation(images)
    init_op = tf.initialize_all_variables()
    saver = tf.train.Saver()
    for i in range(100):
        top_k_op = tf.nn.in_top_k(forward_propgation_results, labels, 1)

  with tf.Session(graph = g) as sess:
    sess.run(init_op)
    tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess)
    saver.restore(sess, eval_dir)

    print(sess.run(top_k_op))

def main(argv = None):
    evaluate()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  tf.app.run()
```

Below that is the Process.Input() code which also may help aid in solving the issue.

```
def eval_inputs():
  data_dir = FLAGS.data_dir
  images, labels = Input.eval_inputs(data_dir = data_dir, batch_size = 1)
  return images, labels
```

Comment: What does your code with the loop look like?

Comment: [True] but printed over 100 times. Which cannot be possible. I think it's computing the same label over and over again.

Comment: Can you include the code for the loop in your question?

Comment: Okay. It has changed but if the formatting is strange. It is my phone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To evaluate all of the images, you must put the loop around the `sess.run()` call:

```
def evaluate():
  with tf.Graph().as_default() as g:
    images, labels = Process.eval_inputs()
    forward_propgation_results = Process.forward_propagation(images)
    init_op = tf.initialize_all_variables()
    saver = tf.train.Saver()

    # Only create a single `top_k_op`.
    top_k_op = tf.nn.in_top_k(forward_propgation_results, labels, 1)

  with tf.Session(graph = g) as sess:
    sess.run(init_op)
    tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess)
    saver.restore(sess, eval_dir)

    # Evaluate the first 100 images in the `eval_inputs()`.
    for i in range(100):
      print(sess.run(top_k_op))
```

In the question, you create the same op 100 times. This is equivalent to calling the same function 100 times on the same input, which explains why the result is the same each time.

The `eval_inputs()` function acts like a Python generator, which returns a different evaluation input example in each call to `sess.run(top_k_op)`. Therefore, if you wrap `sess.run(top_k_op)` in a loop, you will get evaluation results for different examples.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response but I am afraid the same error is still happening. It is statistically improbable that all 100 examples end up being accurate. And all examples in another file being all false.

Comment: Perhaps there is an error in the `Process.eval_inputs()` function that causes it to return the same example each time. Try doing `print(sess.run([labels, top_k_op]))` in the loop to see if the label is changing from one example to the next.

Comment: Okay. The values are the same.

Comment: In that case, the problem is in `Process.eval_inputs()` (or something that it calls).

Comment: I put in the eval.py code. Can you also solve it? Perhaps in another question?